# Problema al provocar excepcion InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Tengo un problema después de que me salte la excepción sobre el atributo `edat`.
El problema es que cuándo me salta el error y me lo captura en vez de preguntarme la siguiente pregunta que seria el `dni` me salta directamente a preguntar la población, es decir, se salta la parte del `dni`.

Os dejo el código:

```
System.out.printf("Introdueix la edat ");
try {
    edat = pregunta.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException m) {
    System.err.println("Exception: " + m);
}
System.out.printf("Introdueix el dni ");
dni = pregunta.next();
System.out.printf("Introdueix la provincia ");
provincia = pregunta.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el método `nextInt()` no consume una nueva línea porque es convertido a `int` por lo que no puede tener una *nueva línea*.

Lo mejor sería utilizar `nextLine()` y hacer un `cast` a `int` con eso no se produce ese comportamiento "raro" o inesperado:

```
System.out.print("Introdueix la edat ");

try {
    edat = Integer.parseInt(pregunta.nextLine());

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                
}

System.out.print("Introdueix la provincia ");
provincia = pregunta.nextLine();

System.out.print("Introdueix el dni ");
dni = pregunta.nextLine();
```